# Perl 6: writable multidimensional subscript access with AT-POS

Tags: raku

You can easily allow subscript access to your own classes using `AT-POS`:

```perl6
class Foo
{
    has @.grid;

    method AT-POS($x) is rw { return-rw @!grid[$x] }
    method Str { '<' ~ @!grid.join(' ') ~ '>' }
    method gist { self.Str }
}

my $foo = Foo.new(:grid(<a b c d e>));
say $foo;
say $foo[2];
$foo[3] = 'z';
say $foo;
```

output:

```
<a b c d e>
c
<a b c z e>
```

But I need two-dimensional subscript access.  I've figured out how to make this work for reading, but it dies when writing:

```perl6
class Bar
{
    has @.grid;

    method AT-POS($y, $x) is rw { return-rw @!grid[$y;$x] }
    method Str { '<' ~ @!grid».join(' ').join("\n ") ~ '>' }
    method gist { self.Str }
}

my $bar = Bar.new(:grid(<a b c d e>, <f g h i j>, <k l m n o>));
say $bar;
say $bar[1;2];
$bar[2;3] = 'z';
say $bar;
```

output:

```
<a b c d e
 f g h i j
 k l m n o>
h
Too few positionals passed; expected 3 arguments but got 2
  in method AT-POS at ./p6subscript line 25
  in block <unit> at ./p6subscript line 33
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: First, `2;3` is a semilist, that is, a list of lists. If you change that to `$bar[2,3]` it's not goint to complain; however, it's not going to be calling AT-POS either.

Comment: `$bar[2,3]` isn't a multidimensional subscript, so not what I need here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution would be (provided we only have 2 dimensions):

```
class Bar {
    has @.grid;

    method TWEAK() { $_ .= Array for @!grid }
    method AT-POS(|c) is raw { @!grid.AT-POS(|c) }
    method Str { '<' ~ @!grid».join(' ').join("\n ") ~ '>' }
    method gist { self.Str }
}
```

The `TWEAK` will convert any lists that were given to arrays if they're not already.  The `is raw` on `AT-POS` is all that is needed: `return-rw` is a very roundabout way of doing that.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!

Answer (score 5):

Somehow, the `AT-POS` method is not being called. The [documentation](https://docs.raku.org/language/subscripts#method_ASSIGN-POS) mentions the use of `ASSIGN-POS` instead, so here we go:

```perl6
class Bar
{
    has @.grid is rw;

    method AT-POS($y, $x) is rw { say "AT-POS $y, $x"; return-rw @!grid[$y;$x] }
    method ASSIGN-POS($y, $x, $new) { say "ASSIGN-POS $y, $x"; @!grid[$y;$x] = $new }
    method Str { '<' ~ @!grid».join(' ').join("\n ") ~ '>' }
    method gist { self.Str }
}

my $bar = Bar.new(:grid(<a b c d e>, <f g h i j>, <k l m n o>));
say $bar;
say $bar[1;2];
$bar[2;3] = 'z';
say $bar;
```

Which, interestingly, yields another error:

```perl6
Cannot modify an immutable List ((k l m n o))
  in method ASSIGN-POS at semilist-so.p6 line 8
  in block <unit> at semilist-so.p6 line 16
```

So the problem is not really the syntax, but the fact that you are working with immutable lists. You should use `Array`s, which are mutable, and you'll be able to do that.

```perl6
class Bar
{
    has @.grid is rw;

    method AT-POS($y, $x) is rw { return-rw @!grid[$y;$x] }
    method ASSIGN-POS($y, $x, $new) { @!grid[$y;$x] = $new }
    method Str { '<' ~ @!grid».join(' ').join("\n ") ~ '>' }
    method gist { self.Str }
}

my $bar = Bar.new(:grid([<a b c d e>], [<f g h i j>], [<k l m n o>]));
say $bar;
say $bar[1;2];
$bar[2;3] = 'z';
say $bar;
```

Comment: Thanks, that'll teach me to skim through the documentation.   I've taken the liberty to add a working example to your answer.  Also removed the `rw` stuff, since it's not necessary anymore.  Still, it's weird that my original one-dimensional example worked while the two-dimensional example bailed.

Comment: Actually, after (finally) reading the documentation more carefully, you _should_ make `AT-POS` `rw`, as `ASSIGN-POS` is only used in simple cases; so I restored that.  (And `$bar[0;0]++` does indeed actually work.)

Comment: `ASSIGN-POS` is [documented](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/ASSIGN-POS) to be optional. If it fails with `AT-POS` alone, you might want to file a bug report...

Comment: I tried one more thing: `multi method AT-POS($y, $x) is rw { return-rw @!grid[$y;$x] }; multi method AT-POS($y) is rw { return-rw @!grid[$y] }`.  This actually works (without `ASSIGN-POS`).  Looks like, when assigning, both variants of `AT-POS` are called for some reason; the actual assignment is to the correct one.