# How can I implement 2d subscripts via AT-POS for different classes?

Tags: raku

here is an MRE (showing two attempts, with debug left in to be helpful) to try and get 2d subscripting working with AT-POS across a DataFrame that has columns of Series...

```
class Series does Positional {
    has Real @.data = [0.1,0.2,0.3];

    method AT-POS( $p ) { 
        @!data[$p]
    }   
}

class DataFrame does Positional {
    has Series @.series;

#`[ ATTEMPT #1
    method AT-POS( $p, $q? ) { 
        given $q {
            when Int {                  #say 'Int';
                @!series[$p][$q]
            }   
            when Whatever {             #say '*';
                @!series[$p].data 
            }   
            default {                   #say 'default';
                @!series[$p] 
            }   

        }   
    }   
#]
    # ATTEMPT #2
    method AT-POS(|c) is raw { #`[dd c;] @!series.AT-POS(|c) }
}

my $df = DataFrame.new( series => [Series.new xx 3] );

say $df[1].data;            #[0.1 0.2 0.3]
say $df[1][2];              #0.3
say $df[0,1];               #(Series.new(data => $[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]) Series.new(data => $[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]))
say $df[1;2];               #0.3
say $df[1;*];               #got (0.1) ... expected [0.1 0.2 0.3]
say $df[*;1];               #got (0.2) ... wanted [0.2 0.2 0.2]
```

I already researched on SO and found three related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54685935/how-to-define-the-at-pos-method), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63210232/support-whatever-ranges-in-multidimensional-subscript-access-with-at-pos) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53802528/perl-6-writable-multidimensional-subscript-access-with-at-pos) ... and the attempt #2 in my code seeks to apply @lizmats Answer to the third one. Encouragingly both the attempts in my MRE have the same behaviour. But I cannot workout

- why the `when Whatever {}` option is not entered (attempt #1)
- what the `|c` is doing - even though I can see that it works in the single subscript case (attempt #2)

I have done some experimenting with `multi postcircumfix:<[ ]>( DataFrame:D $df, @slicer where Range|List ) is export {}` but this seems to overcomplicate matters.

==================

Great answer from @jonathan building on the original from @Lizmat - thanks! Here is the final, working code:

```
class Series does Positional {
    has Real @.data = [0.1,0.2,0.3];

    method elems {
        @!data.elems
    }   

    method AT-POS( |p ) is raw {
        @!data.AT-POS( |p )
    }   
}

class DataFrame does Positional {
    has Series @.series;

    method elems { 
        @!series.elems
    }   

    method AT-POS( |p ) is raw { 
        @!series.AT-POS( |p )
    }   
}

my $df = DataFrame.new( series => Series.new xx 3 );

say $df[1].data;            #[0.1 0.2 0.3]
say $df[1][2];              #0.3
say $df[0,1];               #(Series.new(data => $[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]) Series.new(data => $[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]))
say $df[1;2];               #0.3
say $df[1;*];               #(0.1 0.2 0.3)
say $df[*;1];               #(0.2 0.2 0.2)
```

Comment: You may be able to simplify the code by using [`handles`](https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem#index-entry-handles_trait-handles): `class Series does Positional { has Real @.data handles <elems AT-POS> = [0.1,0.2,0.3] }`. Then again I see you have an `is raw` on the `AT-POS` so maybe that can't just be delegated.

Comment: thanks @raiph ... it is slowly dawning on me the power of the [] ... for now this is a black box incantation for me!

Comment: `[...]` is an operator. All operators are functions. (Same goes for everything else in the language -- declarators and other keywords, traits, etc. Everything is a function. Or rather a method that may be statically mapped to a function.). Functions can do anything. All functions (and hence all operators, traits, etc) are multiple dispatch, so they are arbitrarily extensible for arbitrary user defined types of values that can be added to a module and uploaded to onto raku.land. It's the Perl/CPAN vision, but [from the ground up](https://gist.github.com/raiph/849a4a9d8875542fb86df2b2eda89296).

Comment: To be clear, the `handles` code isn't about `[...]`. It's about delegating methods -- just as you did with your code -- but [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)ly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `AT-POS` method is only ever passed integer array indices.

The logic to handle slicing (with `*`, ranges, other iterables, the zen slice) is located in the array indexing operator, which is implemented as the multiple-dispatch subroutine `postcircumfix:<[ ]>` for single-dimension indexing and `postcircumfix:<[; ]>` for multi-dimension indexing. The idea is that a class that wants to act as an array-alike need not worry about re-implementing all of the slicing behavior and, further, that the slicing behavior will behave consistently over different user-defined types.

For slicing to work, one must implement `elems` as well as `AT-POS`. Adding:

```
method elems() { @!data.elems }
```

Is `Series` and:

```
method elems() { @!series.elems }
```

In `DataFrame` gives the results you're looking for.

If one really wants different slicing semantics, or a far more efficient implementation than the standard one is possible, one can also add `multi` candidates for the indexing operator (remembering to mark them `is export`).

Comment: And/Or use [Array::Agnostic](https://raku.land/zef:lizmat/Array::Agnostic)  :-)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is simply an elaboration of the point @raiph made in a comment:

> You may be able to simplify the code by using [handles](https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem#index-entry-handles_trait-handles)

Indeed you can – so much so that I thought it was worth showing what that would look like in a code block without a comment's formatting limits.

Using `handles`, you can simplify each of the two classes from 9 non-whitespace lines to 3:

```raku
class Series does Positional {
    has Real @.data handles <elems AT-POS> = [0.1,0.2,0.3];
}

class DataFrame does Positional {
    has Series @.series handles <elems AT-POS>;
}
```

(or you could even have each class on 1 line, if you format them the way I'd be tempted to.)

This code produces all the same results to the `say` statements from the code in the question.